# Symfony2 simple result cache?

Tags: php, caching, symfony

I need a really simple Key-Value-Cache in Symfony.
 Something like that, without any Doctrine or HTTP-caching.

```
<?php
$cacheKey = 'blabla';
if(!$cache->has($cacheKey)) {
    // do some heavy work...
    $cache->set($cacheKey, $heavyWorkResult);
}
$result = $cache->get($cacheKey);
```

Did I miss it in the manual or do I need another bundle?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you not google? Or take a look at [knpbundles.com](http://www.knpbundles.com) and search there for "Cache":

http://knpbundles.com/search?q=Cache

Maybe this is something for your needs:

https://github.com/winzou/CacheBundle

**Usage:**

```
$cache = $this->get('winzou_cache.apc');
// or
$cache = $this->get('winzou_cache.file');
// or
$cache = $this->get('winzou_cache.memcache');
// or
$cache = $this->get('winzou_cache.array');
// or
$cache = $this->get('winzou_cache.xcache');
// or
$cache = $this->get('winzou_cache.zenddata');
// or
$cache = $this->get('winzou_cache'); // in that case, it will use the default driver     defined in config.yml, see below

$cache->save('bar', array('foo', 'bar'));

if ($cache->contains('bar')) {
    $bar = $cache->fetch('bar');
}

$cache->delete('bar');
```

***Edit:***

It's not a good idea to use the session for this. Session is per user and cached values can not be shared. And when you use the session you have to think about serialization and other problems that can occurred when you store complex object in session.

Comment: From his example, I suppose that he doesn't need a cache mech. or - even worst - an entire bundle for Cache. 
I suppose that session is the way, if that example is a valid one (even better than cache)

Comment: Do you really store for instance PHP-Objects in your Session? Think about Doctrine records!

Comment: Ok, I hoped there where a simple solution without any bundles. I'll take a look on it. Session is not a good idea, because the cache is supposed for all users and the amount of data is too much.

Comment: @Daniel : yeah, you're right. I had not thought enough before answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use https://github.com/doctrine/cache (the cache system used by doctrine now in standalone)

Answer (score 1):

I've used the LiipDoctrineCache which although it utilises the Doctrine cache, it supports multiple data stores - including the file system and APC.

https://github.com/liip/LiipDoctrineCacheBundle

Here's how I use it to cache external API responses:

```
$cache_driver = $container->get('liip_doctrine_cache.ns.YOUR_NAME');

if ($cache_driver->contains($cache_key)) {
   return $this->cache_driver->fetch($cache_key);
}

// Do something expensive here...

$cache_driver->save($cache_key, "Mixed Data", strtotime('4 hours'));
```

Answer (score 0):

From Symfony documentation:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session = new Session();
$session->start();

// set and get session attributes
$session->set('name', 'Drak');
$session->get('name');
```

http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html